# Create a procedure/function that creates new sequence

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to create a new procedure/function in Postgres that creates a new sequence.
The procedure/function will get the name of the sequence as a variable and creates it.
I tried to follow the documentation but it's not very helpful. This is what I've got so far but it's not working (of course):

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_seq(text) RETURNS text  
    AS 'CREATE SEQUENCE $1 START 100;'
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

````
ERROR:  return type mismatch in a function declared to return text
DETAIL:  Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "create_seq"```
````

Comment: Do you really want to have your function return the `text` of that SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for that, parameters can't be used as identifiers.

To properly deal with names that potentially need quoting, it is highly recommended to use the [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function to generate the SQL.

And you need to declare the function as `returns void` as you don't want to return anything.

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_seq(p_seq_name, text) 
  RETURNS void
AS
$$
begin
 execute format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I START 100', p_seq_name);
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you are on Postgres 11, you could also use a procedure instead of a function for that.

Answer (score 2):

you need use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) like said @a_horse_with_no_name, but you need use  the plpgsql language not sql language for the function, for  remember *return void*,example,:

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_seq_plpgsql(p_seq_name text) 
 RETURNS void
AS
$$
begin
 execute format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I START 100', p_seq_name);
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```